# dynamic date range of one year in Proc SQL pass through query

Tags: sql, sas, proc

New to SAS and SQL and struggling to create a dynamic range in PROC SQL.

As of now, code is hard coded as -

xxxx.xx_ccyymm_xx between '201607' and '201706'. Trying to create a dynamic range so that next month when it is run, it takes on values as 201608 and 201707.

*the variable stores date as in string format

Someone please suggest a way out!!

Sincere Thanks in advance.

Comment: SQl Server Version

Comment: Hi, it sounds lame but can you give me a general code approach. Not sure what SQL server version is this :( I am working on Virtual machine.

Comment: just presses enter, before i finished. I am using sas eg 7.1 if that helps.

Comment: You mentioned pass thru SQL in your title, but not in the actual question. Are you really using pass thru SQL?  It could make a difference as some flavors of SQL will not recognize text quoted using double quote characters as string literals like SAS code does.

Answer (score 1):

In `proc sql`:

```
. . .
where xxxx.xx_ccyymm_xx <= put(today(), yymmn6.) and
      xxxx.xx_ccyymm_xx <= put(intnx('year', today(), 1), yymmn6.)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use macro variables to hold the strings.  You can use %SYSFUNC() to call the INTNX() function to adjust the date by months.  You could use the automatic macro variable &SYSDATE9 to have the day your SAS session started in DATE9 format, or call the DATE() function to get the actual current date.

```
%let today=%sysfunc(date(),date9);
```

Then you can generate your YYYYMM format strings from that.

```
%let current_month=%sysfunc(putn("&today"d,yymmn6));
%let start_month=%sysfunc(intnx(month,"&today"d,-11),yymmn6);
```

Then in your query use the macro variables

```
where myvar between "&start_month" and "&current_month"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have it apply based on run-time:

```
xxxx.xx_ccyymm_xx between
  left(convert(varchar,dateadd(month,-11,getdate()),112),6)
    and 
  left(convert(varchar,getdate(),112),6)
```

Comment: Hi, thank you fo rthe swift response. I tried and still getting 0 records from the query. I am now certain that xxxx.xx_ccyymm_xx is in string format and not in date format. Any suggested edits??!!!